# Implementing C++ -to-lua observer pattern?

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I have an observer (or "listener") pattern implemented in my code as such:

```
struct EntityListener
{
public:
    virtual void entityModified(Entity& e) = 0;
};

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    void setListener(EntityListener* listener);
private:
    EntityListener* m_listener;
};
```

Now, this works in C++; the Entity class calls the `entityModified()` method whenever it needs. Now, I'd like to transfer some of the functionality to Lua, and among those function points is this listener callback. The entities are now created from the Lua scripts. The question is, how do I achieve the listener functionality in Lua?

For example, the Lua script currently does something like this:

```
function initializeEntity()
    -- The entity object is actually created in C++ by the helper
    Entity = Helper.createEntity()

    -- Here I'd like to hook a Lua function as the Entity's listener
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to have a `LuaListener` class in your C++ code that contains a "pointer" to the Lua function, and a Lua-specific `setListener` function that is called from the Lua script that takes a Lua function as argument, and creates a `LuaListener` instance and passes that to the actual C++ `setListener`.

---

So the Lua code would look something like

```lua
function onModified(entity)
  -- ...
end

function initializeEntity()
    entity = Helper.createEntity()
    entity.setListener(onModified)
end
```

And the C++ code would look something like (pseudoish-code only):

```cpp
class LuaListener : public EntityListener
{
private:
    lua_State* state;
    std::string funcName;

public:
    void entityModified(Entity& e)
    {
        // Call function `funcName` in `state`, passing `e` as argument
    }
};

class LuaEntity : public Entity
{
public:
    void setListenerLua(state, funcName, ...)
    {
        Entity::setListener(new LuaListener(state, funcName, ...));
    }
};
```