# How to listen to specific function call in Lua from C++?

Tags: c++, lua, listener

Let's say I have the following Lua code.

```
function touched(x, y)
end
function moved(x, y)
end
function released(x, y)
end
```

These functions are called from C++ with `lua_pcall` so I can also listen to these events in C++.

But I wonder if it's possible to add a listener that listens to specific Lua function based on the name of that function in C++.

For example, it can be something like the following in C++

`lua_addlistener(L, "touched", this, &MyClass::touchedFromLua);`

And then it can listen to the `touched` function in Lua code. (if the function "touched" exists)

Is this possible to do something similar?

Comment: Maybe you can utilize an observer pattern? Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249195/implementing-c-to-lua-observer-pattern) post for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the function with your own and then in that function call the original after you handled the listener:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "touched");
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, this);
lua_pushcclosure(L, &MyClass::touchedFromLua, 2); 
//add  original function and this as upvalues
lua_setglobal(L, "touched");
```

touchedFromLua would have to be static and look something like:

```
int MyClass::touchedFromLua(Lua_State *L){
    int args = lua_gettop(L);
    MyClass* thiz = std::reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(lua_touserdata(lua_upvalueindex(2)));
    thiz->touchedFromLua_nonstatic(L);

    lua_pushvalue(lua_upvalueindex(1));
    lua_insert(L, 1);
    lua_call(L, args , LUA_MULTRET);
    int rets = lua_gettop(L);
    return rets;
}
```

Comment: `lua_touserdata` returns `void *`, so `static_cast<MyClass*>` should be sufficient.  No need for `reinterpret_cast` (which is, by the way, not in the `std` namespace).